# mount encrypted remote folder (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, 18.04, mount, encryption, rsync

I wish to mount an encrypted remote folder on my computer running Ubuntu Server. My remote folder is in a device behind a router. My aim is to do `rsync` from my computer to that folder.

How can I mount such a folder? Is `mount` enough?

Which ports have I to open in the router? It's enough to open port 22?

Comment: You need to mount the encrypted partition your folder is in on the remote machine in some way first. Then you can mount the folder like any other, e.g. via NFS.

Comment: Could you explain with code or a reference?

Comment: [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) is how you use NFS. The rest I guess you should be able to figure out yourself if you're using remote servers with encrypted volumes. At least there's not much more to help with if we don't know details about your setup.